# Where find sound designer for game jam

Tags: job, video-games

Hello everybody,

I'm not sure if this forum allow this kind of question, but we want participate to a game jam ( ludumdare#27  ) and we are looking for a game sound designer to come in ur team.

If someone can give us some forums/community it will be great :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sub-forum at IndieGamer where you can search for a person / read classifieds:
http://forums.indiegamer.com/forumdisplay.php?13-Music-amp-Sound-Portfolios

Answer (score -1):

https://www.facebook.com/scott.bradley.5492

please contact me and we may talk about

hi mate

Answer (score -1):

Facebook.com/soundsrealproductions

Contact me as well.

Thank you